# How to resolve this error? "RestartFreqExceeded: 5 in 1s" in django+celery+rabbitmq+mysql+redis

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, djcelery

So I am using django with celery. rabbitmq is the broker. redis is the cache. mysql is the db. (everything in localhost)

1. I am using python2.7 and using virtualenv based virtual environment
2. I start the redis server (local) at default port
3. In a new terminal, I run

   ```
   python manage.py runserver
   ```
4. In a new terminal I start celery like so

   ```
   celery -A ds_django worker -B -l warning
   ```

And this procedure used to work. But now when I run the celery command, I get the following

```
    [2016-07-12 09:15:20,113: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Frequent restarts detected: RestartFreqExceeded('5 in 1s',)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/user/Desktop/ds-django/ds_django/newDs/lib/python2.7/site- packages/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 285, in start
            self._restart_state.step()
        File "/Users/user/Desktop/ds-django/ds_django/newDs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/common.py", line 130, in step
            raise self.RestartFreqExceeded("%r in %rs" % (R, self.maxT))
     RestartFreqExceeded: 5 in 1s
```

I have absolutely no clue why this is happening or how to fix this. I have searched Google and StackOverFlow over and over again, but no use.

One reason why I think it might have happened is, sometime back I had run 4 celery workers at-a-time and then cold-shut them all down. Maybe because of that it is saying restart frequency exceeded, but not sure. And no idea how to fix this. Probably some config file setting, but which setting and where also no clue.

If any other info is required, I will provide. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I suspect that this is because of the RabbitMQ connectivity issue ? Can you check accessing RabbitMQ

Comment: I used to access rabbitmq console using http://localhost:15672/#/queues. Now when I try it says "undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs" @Backtrack

Comment: which means, Your RabbitMQ is down.  Please start it and give a try

Comment: Any update ? Did you try after starting RabbitMQ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, `Your RabbitMQ is down` due to that consumer started to reconncet and it went to contineous loop and it created an exception `RestartFreqExceeded`. Please try starting your `RabbitMQ` server and run your celery.

Comment: I have been trying that @Backtrack. Same error still. I uninstalled and installed rabbitmq (using homebrew). No use. Still the same error

Comment: @RajJain, Are you able to access RabbitMQ ?

Comment: @RajJain, Are you giving localhost to connect of remote ip in the consumer ?

Comment: I get this when I run `rabbitmqctl status`

[{pid,3641},
 {running_applications,[{os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.4"},
                        {ssl,"Erlang/OTP SSL application","7.3"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.13.3"},
                        {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.6.1"},
                        {public_key,"Public key infrastructure","1.1.1"},
                        {asn1,"The Erlang ASN1 compiler version 4.0.2",
                              "4.0.2"},
                        {syntax_tools,"Syntax tools","1.7"},

and so on @Backtrack

Comment: How are you connecting from consumer ? Are you using localhost or remote IP ?

Comment: i am using localhost

Comment: @RajJain, Are you running the celery task from same machine ?

Comment: yes @Backtrack. everything is local and at localhost

Comment: update:

I run `brew services start rabbitmq`, it says already started. when I run `rabbitmqadmin list queues` it says connection refused. when I go to management console, it says unable to connect to it

Comment: `rabbitmq-server`
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "localhost"

and then http://localhost:15672/#/queues, it says "undefined: There is no template at js/tmpl/login.ejs" again

Comment: @RajJain  Which means you are still having RabbitMQ connection issue. Which OS are you suing ?

Comment: Mac OS X @Backtrack

Comment: @RajJain - Can you run this : rabbitmqctl status and check the status. Please follow this  :https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-standalone-mac.html

Comment: I did that. i reinstalled again. And then when i run `rabbitmq-server` stops at `Starting broker...` for almost forever @Backtrack

Comment: Please check the above link

Comment: The answer is correct. there was some problem with my rabbitmq. I uninstalled rabbitmq, deleted ALL files regarding it (with the help of my senior), then reinstalled and it worked :) but the above link was not so useful :) @Backtrack

Comment: @RajJain, Consider upvoting :) glad it could help

Comment: i did! but apparently due to less than 15 rep, it won't show in public lol. when my rep becomes more than 15, it will show. So fingers-croosed :)

Comment: @RajJain, :). lol. Plz follow this 2 links, We are using celery in PRD and the follwoing links will be useful.   https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/  https://blog.balthazar-rouberol.com/celery-best-practices

Comment: Nice!! Thanks @Backtrack

Comment: I'm seeing this error and my RabbitMQ server is just fine.

Comment: @Cerin - When you say the Rabbitmq is running fine - How did you verify that ? Are you running both Celery and Rabbit on the same server ?

Comment: I saw a recent down vote - dear down voters please leave your message.  I think i have helped OP to resolve this issue. If my answer did not help you please create one. I am happy to help you.